# Ubuntu/Gnome copy and paste problem

Tags: vim, ubuntu, vi

I am having a peculiar problem with copying and pasting from a terminal in vim.  Sporadically, copy-paste will refuse to work.  Control-Shift-C and Control-Shift-V cause nothing.  Often, after copying, paste menus will be disabled.

This is enough of an irritation that I would like to know if others are having the same difficulty.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  but I just select the text with mouse and then use middle (or double side) click.

Would that suit you?

Comment: This does not work for me.  It is an intermittent problem and probably represents the dentition of an actual bug!

Comment: I prefer this way too.
@ncmathsadist: it doesn't work, you should try to reinstall vim.

Answer (score 0):

I use vim's registers to paste text, even from other GUI applications:

- Select text in an application, paste
  it in vim via `"*p`
- Select text in vim via`"*y`,
  paste it to another application.